# Jekyll is not detecting when a new folder is added

Tags: ruby, jekyll, watch

I'm using Jekyll to create a new site. I'm using the command `jekyll serve --watch` to automatically rebuild the site each time a change is made.

This is working great so long as I make a change to an existing file. However, if I add a new folder, Jekyll does not notice it. I have stop Jekyll from watching, then restart it for it to notice the new folder and include it in my _site directory.

Is this expected behaviour or is there likely a problem with my setup?

Comment: What OS, what ruby version, what jekyll version?

Comment: Mac OS 10.7.5, Ruby Version 2.0.0p247, and Jekyll version 1.0.3

Answer (score 2):

The same thing happens with my Jekyll. I believe the `jekyll serve --watch` command looks in the current directories for changes, not newly created ones.